# Nodejs+Express Dropping Requests

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

My express app drops some requests intermittently. I've debugged it to a point where I see a server socket close before the router finishes processing. Here's a log snippet.

```
  [ 'Host',
     '<redacted>',
     'Host',
     '<redacted>',
     'X-Real-IP',
     '122.171.219.142',
     'X-Forwarded-For',
     '122.171.219.142',
     'X-Forwarded-server',
     '<redacted>',
     'X-Forwarded-uri',
     '/files/upload/progress?id=8dd96bd094914981951c28855962f38e&_=1433503852576',
     'X-Forwarded-Proto',
     'https',
     'Connection',
     'upgrade',
     'accept',
     'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
     'accept-encoding',
     'gzip, deflate, sdch',
     'accept-language',
     'en-US,en;q=0.8',
     'cookie',
     '<redacted>',
     'referer',
     'https://<redacted>/files/upload',
     'user-agent',
     'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36',
     'x-requested-with',
     'XMLHttpRequest' ],
  url: '/files/upload/progress?id=8dd96bd094914981951c28855962f38e&_=1433503852576',
  method: 1,
  versionMajor: 1,
  versionMinor: 1,
  shouldKeepAlive: true,
  upgrade: false }
Fri, 05 Jun 2015 11:30:50 GMT express:router dispatching GET /files/upload/progress?id=8dd96bd094914981951c28855962f38e&_=1433503852576
Fri, 05 Jun 2015 11:30:50 GMT express:router query  : /files/upload/progress?id=8dd96bd094914981951c28855962f38e&_=1433503852576
Fri, 05 Jun 2015 11:30:50 GMT express:router expressInit  : /files/upload/progress?id=8dd96bd094914981951c28855962f38e&_=1433503852576
Fri, 05 Jun 2015 11:30:50 GMT express:router jsonParser  : /files/upload/progress?id=8dd96bd094914981951c28855962f38e&_=1433503852576
Fri, 05 Jun 2015 11:30:50 GMT express:router urlencodedParser  : /files/upload/progress?id=8dd96bd094914981951c28855962f38e&_=1433503852576
Fri, 05 Jun 2015 11:30:50 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /files/upload/progress?id=8dd96bd094914981951c28855962f38e&_=1433503852576
Fri, 05 Jun 2015 11:30:50 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /files/upload/progress?id=8dd96bd094914981951c28855962f38e&_=1433503852576
Fri, 05 Jun 2015 11:30:50 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /files/upload/progress?id=8dd96bd094914981951c28855962f38e&_=1433503852576
Fri, 05 Jun 2015 11:30:50 GMT express:router cookieParser  : /files/upload/progress?id=8dd96bd094914981951c28855962f38e&_=1433503852576
Fri, 05 Jun 2015 11:30:50 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /files/upload/progress?id=8dd96bd094914981951c28855962f38e&_=1433503852576
HTTP 1735: server socket close
Fri, 05 Jun 2015 11:30:50 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /files/upload/progress?id=8dd96bd094914981951c28855962f38e&_=1433503852576
Fri, 05 Jun 2015 11:30:50 GMT express:router <anonymous>  : /files/upload/progress?id=8dd96bd094914981951c28855962f38e&_=1433503852576
HTTP 1735: write ret = false
HTTP 1735: write ret = false
HTTP 1735: outgoing message end.
```

I get a 502 response and Nginx error log shows upstream prematurely closed connection. In all other successful requests, the `write ret` happens before the `server socket close` and both happen *after* all the router logs.

Node version is 0.12.4
Express version is 4.12.4

This log was generated with NODE_DEBUG=http DEBUG=express:*

Any pointers on how to continue debugging will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post the code

Comment: https://gist.github.com/braindead/e77e23712c1ea11674da

Comment: Update: rolled back to node v0.10.35 where this does not happen. Tried all the 0.12.X versions where this happens consistently. Haven't tried 0.11.X versions till now.

Comment: Could you share your Nginx configuration?

Comment: can you also try with NODE_DEBUG=net and check the logs?

Comment: I would also like to see your app.js or wherever you configure your express.